# How to add custom task to android gradle build for mergeJniLibFolders

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

A bit of background, I have a custom android build type called "prebuilt" which is intended to be deployed to an android system image. I need custom gradle tasks to modify the assets and jniLibs folders so that these are delivered separately from the apk (e.g., my-app-prebuilt.apk, my-app-prebuilt-assets.zip, my-app-rebuilt-libs.zip). I do not want to modify debug or release buildTypes for normal deployment.

Stripping the assets step was fairly easy once I stumbled on the right task `mergeAssets` to modify:

```
buildTypes {
        applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            if (variant.buildType.name == 'prebuilt') {
                variant.mergeAssets.doLast {
                    // Delete from prebuilt build type. It will be delivered in parallel.
                    delete(fileTree(dir: variant.mergeAssets.outputDir, includes: ['**/somestuff/*']))
                }
                // I want mergeJniLibFolders but this doesn't seem to exist?
                variant.mergeJniLibFolders.doLast {
                    delete(fileTree(dir: variant.mergeJniLibs.outputDir, includes: ['**/*.so']))
                }
            }
}
```

I get an error for the mergeJniLibFolders property:

> Could not get unknown property 'mergeJniLibFolders' for object of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.ApplicationVariantImpl.

I was expecting a `mergeJniLibFolders` or `mergePrebuiltJniLibFolders` to be modifiable to perform the second step of deleting the libs. I am starting to splunk through gradle ApplicationVariantImpl.

An aside, the `variant` object is needed to know the outputDir. For some time I was thinking I could make a `task stripPrebuiltAssets << { dependsOn: mergePrebuiltMergeAssets, ...}`, but I wouldn't have the variant object. This is also rather confusing to me.

I am feeling around in the dark and do not have a good sense of what I can "do" with the Android Plugin DSL. I have read through the reference several times and I have a decent understanding of the AppExtension and properties that can be modified, but how does this translate to the hundred tasks in the gradle tree? I seem to be missing a resource to understand this better.

My Android Studio's poor gradle autocomplete is also frustrating. It seems to identify one autocomplete option only if I have already used it. I am using

- Android Studio 3.2.1
- Gradle 4.10.2
- com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1

Bonus question is zipping up the assets and jniLibs that I am stripping in the two rules so that it is available alongside the `my-app-prebuilt.apk`. I roughly understand I need a task of type Zip that will zip the folder `/build/intermediates/transforms/mergeJniLibs/prebuilt/0/lib/` and then delete the folder. I am also expecting `variant.mergeJniLibs.outputDir` to exist but this also seems to be missing.

Cheers for any insight.

Comment: Did you manage to solve your problem? If so, how?